# open html file and add data into it with iteration

Tags: python, django, html-table, django-templates

I have a html file for Invoice. and i want to display some data from my database which can be in multiple rows of a table.

how can i use iteration to show the data in my Invoice.

for example: In an organisation 3 people used a coupon to do a payment. and when invoice would generate all of the three people's name with date and amount i want to display.

```
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-4 border-0"><strong>Sites</strong></th>
              <th class="col-4 border-0"><span><strong>Mode</strong></span></th>
              <th class="col-4 border-0"><span><strong>Amount</strong></span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tbody>
          ---for loop here---
            <tr>
              <td class="col-4 text-1 border-0"> {var 1} </td>
              <td class="col-4 border-0"><span> {var 2} </span></td>
              <td class="col-4 border-0"><span> {var 3} </span></td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

The way i am passing data from views is:

```
    my_dict=[{'var1':'my site', 'var2': 'DIY', 'var3':'111'},
             {'var1':'my site2', 'var2': 'DIY', 'var3':'222'}]
    with open(BACKEND_TEMPLATE + 'Invoice_base.html') as inf:
        txt = inf.read()
        val = txt.format(date=today, invoice_id=str(identity), domain=FRONTEND_DOMAIN,
                         customer_name=(obj.customer.first_name + " " + obj.customer.last_name),
                         company=obj.customer.company_name, contact=obj.customer.phone_number, my_dict=my_dict)
```

how can i achieve that.

The html file is not supporting template tags or may be i am not using it correctly.
if there is an easy solution please help me out!

Comment: You can use: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/ module to modify an html content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank @CyDevos, I am able to achieve what I wanted using BeautifulSoup.
Below is the way I Did.

1. Imported the BeautifulSoup package as Soup.
2. Open the TemplateCreated an Instance of Soup with html data in my case it is as-**val**

```
    with open(BACKEND_TEMPLATE + 'Invoice_base.html') as inf:
        val = inf.read()

    html_data = Soup(val, features="html5")
```

3. Find the tag or class that we want to change.

```
    table_tbody = html_data.find('tbody')
```

4. add your new tag, text, classes or anything you want.

```
    for ele in invoice_ele_list:
        amount = str(ele['amount'])
        # print(amount, type(amount))
        new_row = html_data.new_tag('tr')
        td_site = html_data.new_tag('td')
        td_site.string = ele['site__slug']
        td_mode = html_data.new_tag('td')
        td_amount = html_data.new_tag('td')
        td_site['class'] = "col-4 text-1 border-0"
        td_mode['class'] = td_amount['class'] = "col-4 border-0"
        span_mode = html_data.new_tag('span')
        span_mode.string = ele['payment_for_permit_mode']
        span_amount = html_data.new_tag('span')
        span_amount.string = amount
        td_mode.insert(1, span_mode)
        td_amount.insert(1, span_amount)
        new_row.insert(1, td_site)
        new_row.insert(2, td_mode)
        new_row.insert(3, td_amount)
        table_tbody.insert(3, new_row)
```

For more details i would refer to the docs of [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled in html `{var 1}` should be without space `{var1}` then it should work.

---

Although with django I recommend the following:

In [django Template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#usage) object has a method called Template.render()

1. So change in the html file all the `{var1}` to `{{var1}}`.
2. In your view `my_dict` to `"data": [list of var dicts]`
3. Get your template with `template = django.template.loader.gettemplate('path/to/template)`
4. get your text string from html with `template.render(context=my_dict)`

You might have to modify a little your for loops according to your needs.

Comment: Actually I want to save the template with new name after Myvalues got pasted in the template. I am not rendering on admin site.
Basically its for Invoice Generation.
That's why i opened it as a file and after changing the values i will save it with a new file name and make that downloaded.

Comment: Template.render method is perfect for this. You will only get a html as string. You can then save the string into a new file and rename it how ever you would like.